# jQuery show() and hide() not working

Tags: jquery, toggle

On this [page](http://www.princessly.com/mermaid-strapless-natural-waist-sleeveless-floor-length-tiered-wedding-dress.html), the expected behavior is to display the custom sizes input boxes such as Bust (inch) and Hips (inch) when the user selects 'Custom Size' in the 'Size' select box. What I have now is this:

```
<select name="options[203]" id="select_203"
 class=" required-entry product-custom-option"
 title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice();if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text=='Custom Size'){$('.custom_size').show();}else{$('.custom_size').hide();}">
```

Basically, I used this in there:

```
if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text=='Custom Size'){$('.custom_size').show();}else{$('.custom_size').hide();}
```

And all the elements that can be toggled in this manner have class 'custom_size' which is 'display:none' in the stylesheet styles.css.

But thus far it doesn't seem to work. Any idea why? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are using Prototype library along with jQuery. You should use [jQuery.noConflict()](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries).

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out. It's the noConflict() that has changed the default $ to $j. Now it's working.